# PhoneGap Application Server Side Includes (SSI)

Tags: cordova, ssi

I am new to using PhoneGap and I was wondering (as I believe it basically acts as a server?) is it possible to use Server Side Includes with PhoneGap?

My main header of the files and the footer of the pages are the same and therefore it makes sense to use something like this. But is it possible or is there another way that I have overlooked?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap doesn't act as a server, it just serves html files from the filesystem of your device and then hooks into them using a javascript-bridge from the webview. So using SSI isn't possible however you could do about the same thing using xmlhttprequest to just fetch the content and put it into the current page. That would also save some time by not reloading the page and reinitiating the phonegap bridge.

Comment: Ah I see hadn't realised that so basically the same as opening a HTML file in a browser using file:// etc. I assume?

That is a good idea however about the xmlhttprequest I hadn't thought of that thanks for you're help